# Where should the commas be placed in 'Beloved, son, brother, father, and grandpa'?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Which sentence is correct?

> Beloved, son, brother, father, and grandpa.

or

> Beloved son, brother, father and grandpa.

Context: Our customer wants this phrase on a headstone. They have a comma after beloved and father. I didn't think a comma was appropriate after "beloved" and would be optional after father.

Comment: Which comma are you referring to? The first sentence has two commas that the second doesn't. Don't put a comma between "beloved" and "son",  assuming it is describing a person who is/was a beloved son, and a beloved brother, etc.

Comment: The comma before "and grandpa" is indeed not necessary, but you can use it if you want. It is called a "serial comma" or "series comma", and is used in a list of 3 or more items. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma In this particular example, it might be ambiguous, as we will then ask ourselves if grandpa is also beloved.

Comment: No comma between "beloved" and "son." It's your choice to put the last comma, serial/oxford comma, between "father" and grandpa." Also, if you are referring to your own relatives, capitalize "father," "son," "mother," "brother," and "grandpa." So it would be like this: *Beloved Son, Brother, Father(,) and Grandpa.*

Comment: Our customer wants this phrase on a headstone.  They have a comma after beloved and father.  I didn't think a comma was appropriate after "beloved" and would be optional after father.

Comment: Then you are absolutely right. For such a formal occasion, you can also use only commas and omit the "and" for dramatic effect.

Comment: And on another note, it seems weird that they used the formal father, but the informal grandpa instead of grandfather. Dunno if it's a mistake or if it is intended, but they might have to change one or the other

Answer (score 1):

Except if one of your relatives is called Beloved, no comma !

Comment: You can use a serial comma though. I believe the OP's question is regarding the comma before "and grandpa" and the one after Beloved is just a typo.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen the comma after "father" in the first proposition ! You can indeed, since both "father and grandpa" and "father, and grandpa" present no ambiguity whatsoever.

Comment: It is slightly ambiguous actually. The comma could mean that they are all beloved, except grandpa: "I was gathered with my beloved father, son, and (not so beloved/with) grandpa.

Comment: I missed this one but you're right, there is a slight change in meaning with the Oxford comma, with Grandpa not being that beloved any more.

Comment: I see what you are saying Morgan.  We should add the comma after "father".  Also, just as a side note, on the headstone, all the letters are capital.

Comment: No that's the thing, if you add the comma after "father", we get **Beloved son, brother, father, and grandpa**, where grandpa is being left out from the other "beloved" members.

Comment: He is not necessarily left out, especially since it's the same person, and not someone's father, and another person would be that person's grandfather etc., which would be different people, but it might be ambiguous in that case. Here the same person is the son, father, grandpa etc.